# error: 'create' is not a member of 'cv::Tracker'

Tags: c++, opencv, tracking

İn [this](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d2/d0a/tutorial_introduction_to_tracker.html) official tutorial I got the error in title. What should be the reason?

```
Ptr<Tracker> tracker = Tracker::create( "KCF" );
```

Here the part of tracking.hpp:

```
    @endcode
    of course, you can also add any additional methods of your choice. It should be pointed out,
    however, that it is not expected to have a constructor declared, as creation should be done via
    the corresponding createTracker() method.
   In src/tracker.cpp file add BOILERPLATE_CODE(name,classname) line to the body of
    Tracker::create() method you will find there, like :
@code
        Ptr<Tracker> Tracker::create( const String& trackerType )
        {
          BOILERPLATE_CODE("BOOSTING",TrackerBoosting);
          BOILERPLATE_CODE("MIL",TrackerMIL);
          return Ptr<Tracker>();
        }
@endcode
-   Finally, you should implement the function with signature :
@code
        Ptr<classname> classname::createTracker(const classname::Params &parameters){
            ...
        }
@endcode
```

I am using 3.2.0 release.

Comment: It could be that the tutorial is for version 3.1.0.

Comment: @molbdnilo I can see the create member is there. The 'code' and 'endcode' syntax come from Doxygen. Maybe Doxygen is the problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The code you pasted from `tracking.hpp` isn't actual code, it's just sample code that's part of the documentation. The only relevant code in the [tracking header file](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/tracking/include/opencv2/tracking.hpp) is:

```
#include <opencv2/tracking/tracker.hpp>
#include <opencv2/tracking/tldDataset.hpp>
```

Thus, to see what you're actually importing you need to look at the `tracking/tracker.hpp` file ([here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/tracking/include/opencv2/tracking/tracker.hpp)).

If you do that, you'll see that there's no `static create` method in the `Tracker` class declaration. The method was actually removed in [this commit](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/commit/3ac9e242549a85572739afd232559d2e4baa7e68). So, basically, you're right: the tutorial wasn't updated after the method was removed. You should [report your issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues) to the opencv team.

That being said, to make the tutorial work you'll probably need to replace the line that's not compiling with:

```
Ptr<TrackerKCF> tracker = TrackerKCF::create();
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: yes, it worked. By the way how did you find the commit about the tracker?

Comment: @ffttyy I browsed through the file history [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/commits/master/modules/tracking/include/opencv2/tracking/tracker.hpp), and I saw that the method was there in earlier versions. Then I looked at the latest commits to see when it was removed.